# how to get item from async storage, set the value in a key and then with that value make an axios request to api for response?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been trying to retrieve data from AsyncStorage which I am successfully doing, upon that I resolve the promise and try the set my userObject key to the result, when that is set I want to make an axios call to api, but whenever I do so am receiving the value as undefined as both being asynchronous requests am unable to fix the bug at all, I have tried multiple ways like,upon resolving asyncstorage .then make axios call but that is not working, I have used rerendering the useEffect with userObject, but the api is being call N number of times. And obviously that is a bad fix, below is my code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import HomeTabAssessmentCardComponent from './components/HomeTabAssessmentCardComponent';
import {API} from '../../api';
import HomeTabOverAllDevelopmentCardComponent from './components/HomeTabOverAllDevelopmentCardComponent';
import HomeTabPhysicalGrowthCardComponent from './components/HomeTabPhysicalGrowthCardComponent';
import HomeTabExpertCardComponent from './components/HomeTabExpertCardComponent';
import HomeTabPremiumCardComponent from './components/HomeTabPremiumCardComponent';
import HomeTabPrimeCardComponent from './components/HomeTabPrimeCardComponent';
import HomeTabWeekWiseImagesCardComponent from './components/HomeTabWeekWiseImagesCardComponent';

export default function HomeTabScreen(props) {
  console.log(
    ' ~ file: HomeTabScreen.js ~ line 12 ~ HomeTabScreen ~ props',
    props,
  );
  const {navigation} = props;
  const mHomeTabResponse = null;
  const [mainResponse, setMainResponse] = useState([]);
  const [mAssessmentList, setAssessmentList] = useState([]);
  const [mWeekWiseMediaList, setWeekWiseMedialist] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userObject, setUserObject] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getHomeTabMainAPI();
  }, [userObject]);

  const getData = () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = AsyncStorage.getItem('user_object').then(
        (result) =>
          // console.log('result', JSON.parse(result)),
          setUserObject(JSON.parse(result)),

        // console.log('userssss', userObject),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  const getHomeTabMainAPI = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await API.get(
        `fist part of api?child_id=${userObject.children[0].id}last part of api`,
      );
      console.log('res', response);

      setAssessmentList(response.data.content.assessments.data);
      setWeekWiseMedialist(response.data.content.media_cards.data);
      setTitle(response.data.content.assessments.title);
      setText(response.data.content.assessments.text);

      setMainResponse(response.data.content.assessments.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem('user_object').then(navigation.navigate('login'));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    console.log('Done.');
  };
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FE017E" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', padding: 10}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            marginLeft: '80%',
          }}
          onPress={() => logoutHandler()}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000'}}>
            Log out
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{paddingBottom: 58}}>
        {/* {console.log('view mWeekWiseMediaList - ' + mWeekWiseMediaList)} */}
        {mWeekWiseMediaList !== null && mWeekWiseMediaList.length > 0 ? (
          <HomeTabWeekWiseImagesCardComponent data={mWeekWiseMediaList} />
        ) : (
          <Text></Text>
        )}
        <HomeTabOverAllDevelopmentCardComponent />
        <HomeTabPremiumCardComponent />
        {mAssessmentList &&
          mAssessmentList != '' &&
          mAssessmentList != null &&
          mAssessmentList.length > 1 &&
          userObject != null &&
          userObject != '' &&
          userObject != undefined &&
          userObject.children[0] &&
          userObject.children[0] != null &&
          userObject.children[0] != undefined &&
          userObject.children[0] != '' && (
            <HomeTabAssessmentCardComponent
              data={mAssessmentList}
              title={title}
              text={text}
              navigation={props}
              children={userObject.children[0].id}
            />
          )}

        <HomeTabPrimeCardComponent />
        <HomeTabPhysicalGrowthCardComponent />
        <HomeTabExpertCardComponent />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

As you can see in my endpoint `fist part of api?child_id=${userObject.children[0].id}last part of api` I need to call the userObject.children[0].id key and it should not be null.

Have been stuck with this since very long, any leads would be appreciated.
Please do let me know if anything is required for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API call is not waiting for the getData method to complete as these two methods are run in parallel. I'm guessing this `user_object` will never be null or undefined at this screen (hoping that you are already checking for this value at some higher level, maybe in your router definition). If so you can initially set the `userObject` as null

```js
const [userObject, setUserObject] = useState(null);
```

In your `userObject` side effect, add the below check,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(userObject)
    getHomeTabMainAPI(); 
  else
    getData();
}, [userObject]);
```

This way, the `getData()` method will be called initially, which will fetch the data from `AsyncStorage` and will set the userObject. Change in the `userObject` will trigger the side effect, this time will run the `getHomeTabMainAPI()`.